# How do I print time in a file at different point of execution by opening the file only at the end?

Tags: c

I am trying to print time twice  in a file. The code is shown below.

The output is not coming correct, it is just printing some values which are not what the current time is.

The issue is I have to call `fprintf` **only once  and that too at the last**. **In fact at the last when I will be writing buffer (containing time from several GetLocalTime calls) to a file I can call fprintf several times, that is not an issue.**

I call `GetLocalTime` twice on a `buffer`, it seems the buffer is being overwritten.

Can someone suggest me more elegant way for printing time in the file at different points in execution, and opening file only once ? (if I open file after each GetLocalTime function call, I would be adding the overhead of file open and write etc.  )

**Latest Update: 
 Based on the suggestion I modified the code like this, and It worked**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;

    char *buffer; 

    buffer= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10000); 

    GetLocalTime(&st);



          int offset=0;
offset += sprintf(buffer+offset, "time is %d,%d, %d, %d \n",st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
/*Other code*/

Sleep(1000);

GetLocalTime(&st);

offset += sprintf(buffer+offset, "time is %d,%d, %d, %d \n",st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);


          FILE * p;
          p=fopen("test.txt","a");
          fprintf(p,"%s",buffer);
          fclose(p);



    return 0;
}
```

Now I am getting correct results!!

I am running this code on windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010.

**Additional Info**

I cannot use two different buffers. The reason is in actual code I will be printing time 100s of time, so I will have to create 100s of buffers, which I dont want to do.

What I want to do is this:

```
GetLocalTime(); 

.
. //Now put time in buffer at this point
.
.
GetLocalTime(); 
.

. //Now put time in buffer at this point
.
GetLocalTime(); 

.
.. //Now put time in buffer at this point
.
.
GetLocalTime(); 
  . //Now put time in buffer at this point



.. 

Now put all the times from several calls  in a text file
```

**Ultimately I will get ALL  timings in the text file**

Comment: Declare two buffers instead of just one.  Then print both of them,with a format string like `"%s\n%s\n"`.  (`%c` is incorrect, if you want to print a string rather than a single character).

Comment: @Jim Lewis I cannot use two different buffers. The reason is in actual code I will be printing time 100s of time, so I will have to create 100s of buffers, which I dont want to do.

Comment: Make an array, e.g. `SYSTEMTIME st[200];` and call the function as `GetLocalTime(&st[index]); index++;` where `index` is an `int` that's initialized to 0. Get rid of the `buffer` and just `fprintf` directly from the array into the file.

Comment: Why do you insist on doing a single `fprintf` at the end, instead of printing the timestamps as you go, which would seem like the obvious solution?

Comment: @JimLewis Multiple fopen, fprintf, fclose etc will be costly, and that overhead will add up to my time of execution of code

Comment: Modified my code under Latest Update: Based on the suggestion I modified the code like this

Comment: But you only need 1 call to fopen at the beginning, and 1 call to fclose at the end.  Doing it your way, you would either have to pre-allocate sufficient buffer space to store all the output in memory, or incur the runtime cost of dynamically reallocating your output buffers as they grow.  Maintaining an open file descriptor and writing to it as necessary is an extremely common pattern; to rule this out on performance grounds, without trying it first, seems like a premature optimization, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
int offset=0;
offset += sprintf(buffer+offset, "time is %d,%d, %d, %d \n",st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
/*Other code*/
offset += sprintf(buffer+offset, "time is %d,%d, %d, %d \n",st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);
```

`sprintf` returns the number of characters printed to the buffer.

Every time you call `sprintf()`, keep updating the offset and offset the buffer pointer by that much amount for the next call for `sprintf()`. This way the first timestamp won't get overwritten.

Comment: In that case using `snprintf` is really needed, because the risk of buffer overflow is significant.

Comment: @sanketh Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried that way, but I think I am still doing something wrong. This time I have a malloc for buffer. Kindly see my code under Latest Update.

Comment: If the buffer size is not predictable, a linked list ?
Of course you could have stored it in another file and read it back ? In some shops where reports are accumulated over a long time, from hundreds of concurrent sources,  a database table is used.

Answer (score 0):

sprintf formats the result into the buffer starting at the beginning of the buffer

use two buffers if you want both times to show up in the file, or fprintf to the file
instead of composing into the buffer.  Or, even simpler

```
SYSTEMTIME st1, st2;

GetLocalTime(&st1);
Sleep(1000);
GetLocalTime(&st2);

... etc
```

Comment: I cannot use two different buffers. The reason is in actual code I will be printing time 100s of time, so I will have to create 100s of buffers, which I dont want to do. –

Comment: Kindly see my Update 2